# jQuery is not working for unchecked check box using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is what i am trying to get as result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.i_filter').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.i_filter:checked').each(function() {

      var ele = [];
      ele = $(this).val();

      if ($('.i_filter').is(':checked')) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'filter_product.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            ele: ele
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $("#filter_result").html(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert('Hello');
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'allproduct.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {},
          success: function(data) {
            $("#filter_result").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I want some data when check box is checked and after unchecked all the check boxes all data will be display in the div.

This system i want for creating shopping site filter using checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Something which i used for my case.

```
$('.business-type  input:checkbox').click(function(){
   businessTypeValue=$('.business-type  input:checkbox').map(function(n){
     if(this.checked){
        return  this.value;
      };
   }).get().join(',');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple php code ..

// html page ..

```
<label>Select State</label><br>
<?php 
$allgroup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  state");
$flag=false;
while($state_list = mysql_fetch_array($allgroup))
{
   $parr=explode(',',$er['state_id']);
   $size = sizeof($parr);
   for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) { 
     if($parr[$i]==$state_list['id']) {                              
        $flag=true;
     } 
   }    

  if($flag==true) {
    ?>
    <input  type='checkbox' name='state[]' style="margin-left:5px;" value="<?php echo $state_list['id']; ?>" checked  > <?php echo $state_list['name']; ?> <br>
    <?php
    $flag=false;
  } else { 
    ?>
    <input  type='checkbox' name='state[]' style="margin-left:5px;" value="<?php echo $state_list['id']; ?>"     > <?php echo $state_list['name']; ?> <br>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

// php code ...

```
<?php
$states="";
$i=0;
foreach( $_POST['state'] as $selected) {
   echo sizeof($_POST['state']);
   if($i==sizeof($_POST['state'])-1) {
       $states = $states.$selected;
   } else {
     $states = $states.$selected.",";
   }
   $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't want for php. I want this for jQuery. How to check the checkbox is checked or unchecked.